# How can I get clojure to write a response to a socket?

Tags: java, sockets, http, clojure, response

I've made a socket which will accept any get/post requests on a port.

And for now based on the uri it prints out different strings to the repl.

`/` will just say "hello"

`/whatever` says "hello, whatever"

But now I need to send a response to the browser, this is what I have, but I'm not getting a response in the browser:

```
(def output (.getOutputStream accepted-socket))

(map (fn[char] (.write @output (int char)))

"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: 44\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n

<html><body><h1 Please work!/></body></html>")
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid around `<h1 ... />`, should be: `<h1>Please work!</h1>`

Comment: make sure you flush the output stream. Also, happy to point you to HTTP servers you can use without having to deal with sockets

Comment: As a rule, `map` (being lazy) isn't useful for side effects. See [doseq](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doseq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user=> (import 'java.net.Socket)
java.net.Socket
user=> (def s (Socket. "localhost" 7777))
#'user/s
user=> (with-open [o (io/writer s)]
(.write o "hello, world"))
nil
```